# Need to perform Dimension Reduction on my Dataframe in R

Tags: r, pca

I have a dataset BO which contains more than 40 variable  which are of type INT,FACTOR or NUM .
I need to reduce the number of variables by performing PCA 
In this process i have wrote the following code

```
BO_pca <- prcomp(BO[, sapply(BO, is.numeric)], center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
```

This have given me following error

```
Error in prcomp.default(BO[, sapply(BO, is.numeric)], center = TRUE, scale = TRUE) : 
  cannot rescale a constant/zero column to unit variance
```

Kindly help and also guide me through the further process please

Answer (score 0):

look like similar question: [How to solve prcomp.default(): cannot rescale a constant/zero column to unit variance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315227/how-to-solve-prcomp-default-cannot-rescale-a-constant-zero-column-to-unit-var)

try this and edit ur question with what didnt work

Comment: I am able to get the PCA done but how should i remove the columns on the base of this data?